# Swift & Firebase - update ViewController after Login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've added the possibility for the user to log in via firebase, which works fine. Every time the user logs in, data is being read from the realtime database and added to the app.

When successfully logged in the login view is being dismissed and changed to my "MainViewController". This "MainViewController" displays `startKm` and `currentKm`, but as the login view is being dismissed, **the numbers in the "MainViewController" are not being updated** - only after f.e. changing view again or closing the app.

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let email = emailInput.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordInput.text else { return }

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {
                self.readData()
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("Error logging in: ", error!.localizedDescription)

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Fehler beim Einloggen", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Verstanden", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } 

func readData() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let monthlyStartKmData = value?["monthlyStartKm"] as? Int ?? 0
            let currentKmData = value?["currentKm"] as? Int ?? 0
            ...


            startKm = monthlyStartKmData
            currentKm = currentKmData
            ...


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is the code from your LogIn view controller, or MainViewController?

Comment: @LeviYoder That's the code for the Login - the only thing relevant in MainViewController are the declaration of the labels in viewdidload()

Comment: Where is the code in which you're attempting to pass the values to the MainViewController?

Answer (score 0):

```
startKm = monthlyStartKmData
currentKm = currentKmData
```

This isn't going to assign the variables on your MainViewController, these values will disappear once you've segued to another viewController. I'm not sure how you're changing between viewControllers, but using `prepareForSegue` is helpful when you want to pass values between viewControllers.

place this code in your loginViewController:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MainViewController
       destinationVC.startKm = monthlyStartKmData
       destinationVC.currentKm = currentKmData 
}
```

This should work, assuming you have already declared variables `startKm` and `currentKm' within`MainViewController`, and assuming you're segueing from logInVC to MainViewController.

If there are other segues potentially called on logInVC, add a conditional statement to the `prepareForSegue` call such as:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "MainViewControllerSegue" { //or whatever you call the segue            
 let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MainViewController
           destinationVC.startKm = monthlyStartKmData
           destinationVC.currentKm = currentKmData 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'll try it in a minute, but startKm & currentKm are declared globally - I thought this would do the trick as well..

Comment: Oh okay, understood. I haven't used global variables, so I can't speculate as to why they aren't persisting through your segue, but hopefully this will work for ya.